# after data updating if empty means add button should be display else edit button without page reload using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**Insert/Update data in to database using ajax,without page reload working fine, after data updating if empty means add button should be display else edit button without page reload.below attached my screen shot**

[image: if data exit in database edit else add]
**form**

```
<div class="panel-heading row" id="first">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Company Name</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis" id="cname">
        <?php  if (isset($s_company_name)) {
            echo $s_company_name;
        } ?>
    </div>
    //here if empty means add button should be display else edit button
    <?php  if (empty($s_company_name[0]) || empty($s_company_name)) {  ?>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
            <div class="profile-edit col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Add</div>
        </a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 profile-edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</div>
        </a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                <label class="col-md-4">Company Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type ="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" class="form-control" value="
                    <?php  if (isset($s_company_name)) {
                        echo $s_company_name;
                    } ?>"/>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_company_insert_update',
                data: form_data,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#cname').text($("#company_name").val());
                    // How to call the above if else condition here,if data exit edit button should be display else add button**

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can check your success data whether it's empty or not and then you can use jquery show()/hide() method as per the needs.

Comment: give me one example if possible modify my code...in php i done code above  shown in form,but how to call that code in ajax success function

Answer (score 0):

Write in this way

in HTML

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" >
    <div class="profile-add col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="<?php if (!empty($s_company_name[0])) { "display: none;" } ?>">Add</div>
    <div class="profile-edit col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="<?php  if (empty($s_company_name[0])) { 'display:none;' } ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</div>
</a>
```

and in JS

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_company_insert_update',
                data: form_data,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#cname').text($("#company_name").val());
                    $('.profile-add').hide();
                    $('.profile-edit').show();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: your code is working but problem is data is there in database means add button will display else edit,already exist data will be modified it means also edit...these things are not working @Akshay Singhai

Comment: I'm not getting you point, could you please share the screenshot, what is working and what is not. so that I can help you much better.

Comment: if  already data exist in database it will display Edit button without page refresh else Empty means Add button should be display without page reload...

Comment: i shown image above,example if edit and remove the testing company data from Company Name,after remove the data Add button should be display

Comment: Ok, you are talking about, Let us suppose you have added some company name, so button will change like this ADD->EDIT and when you remove the data and save, it Should be like this EDIT->ADD

Comment: Example starting company name is empty it should be ADD Button ,After click the ADD button enter some data and click the save Now it should be change automatically EDIT button without page reload.. without page reload your code is not working

Comment: My requirement is if don't have data in database it should be ADD button else EDIT button  without page reload button should be change

Comment: Give 2 hrs time, will post soon.

Comment: I have edited in HTML please insert this in your code and test once, that will surely work for you

Comment: yesterday i got solution but one problem is there shal i send link

Comment: Ok share it on aksinghai@outlook.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919626/if-data-exist-in-database-edit-button-should-be-display-else-add-button-without...here first panel is working according to my requirement but second panel is not working same like first panel

Comment: are you got my problem @Akshay Singhai