# If data exist in database Edit button should be display else Add Button without page reload display in ajax success function

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

If the data exist in the database, the Edit button should be displayed, else Add Button should be displayed without page reload display in ajax success function.

In my form the First Panel is working fine with the same code I did in the second panel where it is not working.

**form**

```
<form action="" id="data_form" method="post" > 
    <div class="dashboard-column-main"> 
    <div class="dashboard-container"> 
    <div class="title-section"> 
    <h3 class="section_title">Company Information</h3> 
    </div> 

    <div class="profile-back"> 
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion"> 

    <!--First pannel ends--> 
    <div class="panel panel-default"> 

    <div class="panel-heading row" id="first"> 
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Company Name</div> 
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis" id="cname"><?php 
    if (isset($s_company_name)) { 
    echo $s_company_name; 
    } 
    ?> 
    </div> 

    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> 
    <div class="profile-edit col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 aj-text"> 
    <?php if (empty($s_company_name[0]) || empty($s_company_name)): ?> 
    Add 
    <?php else: ?> 
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit 
    <?php endif; ?> 
    </div> 
    </a> 
    </div> 


    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse"> 
    <div class="panel-body"> 
    <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-offset-2 text-center"> 
    <label class="col-md-4">Company Name</label> 
    <div class="col-md-8"> 
    <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" class="form-control" 
    value="<?= (isset($s_company_name)) ? $s_company_name : null; ?>"/><br> 
    <input type="hidden" name="save_type" id="save_type" value="<?= (empty($s_company_name[0]) || empty($s_company_name)) ? 'Save' : 'Update'; ?>"> 

    <?php if (empty($s_company_name[0]) || empty($s_company_name)): ?> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btn" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse">Save</button> 
    <?php else: ?> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btn" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse">Update</button> 
    <?php endif; ?> 
    <button type="button" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    <!--First pannel ends--> 

    <!--second pannel starts--> 
    <div class="panel panel-default"> 
    <div class="panel-heading row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Company Established Date</div> 
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis" id="cdate"><?php 
    if (isset($s_company_estd_date)) { 
    echo $s_company_estd_date; 
    } 
    ?> 
    </div> 
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"> 
    <div class="profile-edit col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 aj-textt"> 
    <?php if (empty($s_company_estd_date[0]) || empty($s_company_estd_date)): ?> 
    Add 
    <?php else: ?> 
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit 
    <?php endif; ?> 
    </div> 
    </a> 

    </div> 
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse"> 
    <div class="panel-body"> 
    <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-offset-2 text-center"> 
    <label class="col-md-4">Company Established Date</label> 
    <div class="col-md-8"> 
    <input name="company_estd_date" id="company_estd_date" type ="text" class="form-control" value="<?= (isset($s_company_estd_date)) ? $s_company_estd_date : null; ?>"/><br> 
    <input type="hidden" name="save_typee" id="save_typee" value="<?= (empty($s_company_estd_date[0]) || empty($s_company_estd_date)) ? 'Save' : 'Update'; ?>"> 
    <?php if (empty($s_company_estd_date[0]) || empty($s_company_estd_date)): ?> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btnn" data-target="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse">Save</button> 
    <?php else: ?> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success aj-text-btnn" data-target="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse">Update</button> 
    <?php endif; ?> 
    <button type="button" data-target="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
<!--second pannel ends--> 

</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</form> 


<script> 
$(document).ready(function () { 

$('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) { 
e.preventDefault(); 
var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_company_insert_update', 
data: form_data, 
dataType: 'json', 
success: function (result) 
{ 
$(".aj-text").html(result.replace_text); 
$(".aj-text-btn").html(result.btn_text); 
$("#save_type").val(result.save_type); 

$('#cname').text($("#company_name").val()); 





$(".aj-textt").html(result.replace_textt); 
$(".aj-text-btnn").html(result.btn_textt); 
$("#save_typee").val(result.save_typee); 
$('#cdate').text($("#company_estd_date").val()); 

}, 
error: function () 
{ 
alert('failed'); 
} 
}); 
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

**Controller code**

```
public function supplier_company_insert_update() { 

$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('supplier_otherdetails'); 
$this->db->where('supplierid_fk', $this->session->id); 
$query = $this->db->get(); 
$save_type = $this->input->post('save_type'); 
$save_typee = $this->input->post('save_typee'); 
$company_name = $this->input->post('company_name'); 
$cdate = $this->input->post('company_estd_date'); 

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
$this->Profile_model->update_supplier_company(); 
//redirect('welcome/suppliercompany'); 
} else { 
$this->Profile_model->insert_supplier_company(); 
//redirect('welcome/suppliercompany'); 
} 

if (trim($company_name) != '') 
echo json_encode(array('replace_text' => 'Edit', 'btn_text' => 'Update', 'save_type' => $save_type)); 
else 
echo json_encode(array('replace_text' => 'Add', 'btn_text' => 'Save', 'save_type' => $save_type)); 

if (trim($cdate) != '') 
echo json_encode(array('replace_textt' => 'Edit', 'btn_textt' => 'Update', 'save_typee' =>  $save_typee)); 
else 
echo json_encode(array('replace_textt' => 'Add', 'btn_textt' => 'Save', 'save_typee' =>  $save_typee)); 
}
```

Comment: any errors you are getting?

Comment: In my model code if remove the second if statement in controller working fine but  if you add the second if statement without refresh buttons are not changing @ArpitSolanki

Comment: in my form Company Name first panel working fine but second panel is not working

Answer (score 0):

**modified code in controller**

```
 public function supplier_company_insert_update() {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('supplier_otherdetails');
        $this->db->where('supplierid_fk', $this->session->id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $save_type = $this->input->post('save_type');
        $company_name = $this->input->post('company_name');

        $save_typee = $this->input->post('save_typee');
        $cdate = $this->input->post('company_estd_date');

 if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $this->Profile_model->update_supplier_company();
            //redirect('welcome/suppliercompany'); 
        } else {
            $this->Profile_model->insert_supplier_company();
            //redirect('welcome/suppliercompany'); 
        }

        if (trim($company_name) != '')
            $return_name = array('replace_text' => 'Edit', 'btn_text' => 'Update', 'save_type' => $save_type);
        else
            $return_name = array('replace_text' => 'Add', 'btn_text' => 'Save', 'save_type' => $save_type);


        if (trim($cdate) != '')
            $return_cdate = array('replace_textt' => 'Edit', 'btn_textt' => 'Update', 'save_typee' => $save_typee);
        else
            $return_cdate = array('replace_textt' => 'Add', 'btn_textt' => 'Save', 'save_typee' => $save_typee);
        echo json_encode(array_merge($return_name, $return_cdate));
}
```